# ThreadPool is OK, Pool raises RuntimeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

i'm new to Python and i'm trying to organize some kind of timeout, when process hangs. Following code works fine:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
pool = ThreadPool(processes=1)
file_list = []
while not file_list:
     async_result = pool.apply_async(list_retriever,)
     try:
          file_list = async_result.get(15)
     except:
         print('We\'ve got timeout!\n')
```

I've found out that `ThreadPool` is not documented properly, and I've decided to switch to the `Pool` instead. Following code raises RuntimeError:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool
pool = Pool(processes=1)
file_list = []
while not file_list:
     async_result = pool.apply_async(list_retriever,)
     try:
          file_list = async_result.get(15)
     except:
          print('We\'ve got timeout!\n')

    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Bodnya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 106, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd)
  File "C:\Users\Bodnya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 115, in _main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "C:\Users\Bodnya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 226, in prepare
    _fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])
  File "C:\Users\Bodnya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 278, in _fixup_main_from_path
    run_name="__mp_main__")
  File "C:\Users\Bodnya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\runpy.py", line 254, in run_path
    pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
  File "C:\Users\Bodnya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "C:\Users\Bodnya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Bodnya\PycharmProjects\zuf-test-branch\zuf-test\auto-deploy.py", line 69, in <module>
    pool = Pool(processes=1)
  File "C:\Users\Bodnya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 168, in __init__
    self._repopulate_pool()
  File "C:\Users\Bodnya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 233, in _repopulate_pool
    w.start()
  File "C:\Users\Bodnya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 105, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "C:\Users\Bodnya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 313, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\Bodnya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 34, in __init__
    prep_data = spawn.get_preparation_data(process_obj._name)
  File "C:\Users\Bodnya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 144, in get_preparation_data
    _check_not_importing_main()
  File "C:\Users\Bodnya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 137, in _check_not_importing_main
    is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.''')
RuntimeError: 
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
        in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...

        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
```

And this error message keeps showing in the endless loop. Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

UPDATE

Apparently I did not protect the main code like this to avoid creating subprocesses recursively, but why it worked in the first example?

Answer (score 0):

Here's working solution:

```
    def function():
        from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
        pool = ThreadPool(processes=3)
        file_list = []
        for i in range(3)
             async_result = pool.apply_async(list_retriever,)
             try:
                  file_list = async_result.get(15)
             except:
                 print('We\'ve got timeout!\n')
                 continue

    if __name__ == '__main__':
         function()
```

However, still, it soent explain, why it was working in the first place.